# WP theme not displaying properly in FF

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been playing around with themes on a site http://edited The theme is TheProfessional theme from Elegant Themes, I took it right out of the box unchanged, only wordpress plugins installed right now are Akismet and Statcounter, tried disabling, but problem still occurs.

The problem is in firefox only as far as I'm aware (works fine in IE and Chrome), the main post box gets squashed up over the box it should be in, and onto the top menu.
You'll know exactly what I mean when you see it in FF. I've never had format layout issues with WP themes before.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was the theme gets grumpy, but only in firefox, when you don't give it images to handle in the background.

Added pictures, problem solved.